Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on Lenovo Yoga 7 2-in-1 randomly loses touchpad functionality
I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my new Lenovo Yoga 7 2-in-1. When I boot it, the touchpad works well but randomly during the day the touchpad seems to lose the following settings:

Two-finger scrolling (no form of scrolling works on the touchpad, but I can still scroll using the touchscreen)
Touchpad speed (it seems to default to a higher speed than I set it to.
Disable touchpad while typing which causes me to inadvertently click and lose focus when typing.

These problems persist until I reboot the laptop. What can I do to resolve this issue? Is this a driver issue?
Note: I previously had Ubuntu 24 and had similar issues.


Edit: I encountered the problem again and this time I made a copy of /var/log/kern.log. I put the full dump here but I can't seem to find anything in there that would indicate a problem with the touchpad.

plz add you have output from your kernel log when this behaviour triggers

@tomodachi thank you. I waited until I saw the behaviour again and took a copy of /var/log/kern.log . I have updated my question with a link to the log.

I have encountered this problem on similar lenovos.
There is a Touchpad disable key on most lenovo laptops, usually F6 or F8, using fn if necessary.
If you unknowingly bump this key, you might just give up and reboot.

Thank you for your answer. In this case though the touchpad is not completely disabled but loses some of its functionality. It's almost like it defaults to a more generic driver or something.

Have you considered upgrading to the latest Ubuntu LTS 24.04?
Your kernel log contains stack traces, as in crashes in your kernel related to software or firmware incompatibilities or bugs as well as several ACPI errors.
The kernel trace it even suggests upgrading to later firmware something you will get with a more recent Ubuntu release.
It's hard to deduce exactly what can be causing your issue. If you're unable to Upgrade to a recent release you could check with lsmod , if there is a kernel module loaded for the touchpad, try to unload it and load it again to see if that fixes the problem

Yes, I had the same issue with Ubuntu LTS 24.04. In fact I specifically downgraded to Ubuntu 22 because of issues with software and (the lack of) packages that were supported by 24.

I ran the following command and it restored functionality of my touchpad:
sudo modprobe -r i2c_hid_acpi i2c_hid
sudo modprobe i2c_hid_acpi i2c_hid

Still not sure what causes this issue, but the above commands provide a temporary fix.
